# ERROR Docusaurus server-side rendering could not render static page with path

Tags: python-3.x, docusaurus, nbconvert

I am trying to include the markdown files in the docusaurus site, please check the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tfnz.jpg)

these markdown files are actually converted files from jupyter notebooks, i used a python library nbconvert to automate the conversion of jupyter notebooks into markdown files.

When I used these md files in docusaurus site, the yarn build had given some JSX syntax errors even though the look and feel of markdown files is working as expected. I resolved those errors manually. However, now the server side is giving errors to render those templates into the site. I am stuck and not sure which is the cause and how to resolve these to make the site work properly.

Comment: Please, Help others reproduce the problem, see: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)   And please leave out all unneeded comments, like "I got errors.,..... solve manually". When they are solved there is no need to mention it on a different problem.

Comment: @Luuk, i added it to let everyone know about the scenario as i need help in that as well to not to have it in future. I guess that's not a problem. Also, i wanted to know from the expertise as they might have faced it, so reproducing the problem is not the main thing here as its not quite possible. Thanks